# SQL - Find patient that has all availabe diseases

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

Patient

```
pID <<PK>>

pName
```

---

DiseaseList

```
dName <<PK>>
```

---

SuffersFrom (dName and pID are also PK for SuffersFrom)

```
dName <<FK>> 

pID <<FK>>
```

---

**What I want to do is SELECT the name of the the Patient that suffers from all the diseases in DiseaseList** but I really don't know how I'd do this.

I have tried searching the web but didn't find anything that helped me. This is the only task I have left to do for a SQL introduction class and I really cannot think of how to set up the query.

Comment: Simplest way: Start by getting a result set of each patient and how many diseases they have. Then, add a `having` to see where that count matches the total number of rows in the diseases table. The general logic is *"Return patients whose 'Number of Diseases' is the same as the amount of records in the 'diseases' table."* **EDIT:** juergen just posted an answer that does exactly that :)

Comment: Assuming for quarantine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the patient and take only those having the same number of different diseases as there are in the disease table

```
select p.pid, p.pname
from patient p
join suffersFrom s on s.pid = p.pid
group by p.pid, p.pname
having count(distinct s.dname) = (select count(*) from DiseaseList)
```